# Theoretical Expected Maximum Drawdown vs Empirical Maximum Drawdown

Tags: brownian-motion, geometric-brownian, maximum-drawdown, drawdown

I have been looking at the approach for calculating the expected maximum drawdown of a Brownian Motion [1] and the corresponding function maxddStats in the fBasics package in R [2].

I do not understand how for some choices of parameters the value from sampling the maximum drawdown via rmaxdd and the corresponding statistic from maxddStats are so far apart.

```
require(fBasics)

maxddStats(mean = 0.01, sd = 0.0427, horizon = 135)
> 0.3142337
mean(rmaxdd(n = 100000, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.0427, horizon = 135))
> 0.2637941
```

It doesn't seem to be an issue of convergence (increasing small n in rmaxdd), nor of scaling (scaling mean and mu). Am I missing something basic here?

[1] [https://www.cs.rpi.edu/~magdon/ps/journal/drawdown_journal.pdf](https://www.cs.rpi.edu/%7Emagdon/ps/journal/drawdown_journal.pdf)
[2] https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fPortfolio/versions/260.72/topics/DrawdownStatistics

Comment: @noob2 I do not understand the edit, I thought maxddStats is implementing the theoretical expected maximum drawdown as per [1], see the source code: https://github.com/cran/fBasics/blob/master/R/stats-maxdd.R

Comment: Sorry. I will revert.